# Error trying to git commit

Tags: git, gruntjs, githooks, git-commit

When I type:  `git commit .` I get this error:

```
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have no idea where the 'grunt' reference is coming from, but this is the error I am getting when trying to commit.  Any ides on how to fix or where I can start looking for issues?

Comment: I also have no idea what `grunt` has to do with this.  Can you post the entire command you actually ran?

Comment: looks like grunt is no longer installed globally . try with `npm install -g grunt-cli`

Comment: Sorry I dropped the '.' by mistake when posting the question, the entire command was "git commit ."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the project probably contains some git hooks that rely on grunt, perhaps for linting purposes. You should install grunt and any other node modules needed. Like so:

```
npm install -g grunt
```

And then(within the project folder if not already done):

```
npm install
```